# Visual Studio C# .exe runs, but USB HID device quits working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, usb, exe

When I run my C# application in Visual Studio 2013 I can communicate with my custom USB HID device reliably.

When I run the .exe (release or debug) directly, the app runs, but there is no communication with the USB HID device.

I know there are manifest additions required to communicate with App Store applications, but I am building a Windows Forms app.  I can't find any details on enabling USB permission for Windows Forms apps.

Without access to the debugger I don't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the VS is running as admin and you are running your exe as 
non admin (meaning the exe does not have the elevated privileges?) 
COuld you possibly post code or the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I am not really happy with it.  It appears to be timing related.  It was not permission related.

I write a USB HID packet to my device, then read a response packet.

When running the .exe outside of Visual Studio it somehow thinks there is a response immediately after sending the write packet.

If I put:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
```

between the write packet command and the read packet command it functions just like it does inside Visual Studio.

Is this enough for anyone to guess the root cause?

Write report code:

```
var success = Kernel32.WriteFile(
                deviceInformation.WriteHandle,
                outputReportBuffer,
                outputReportBuffer.Length,
                ref numberOfBytesWritten,
                IntPtr.Zero);

Debug.WriteLine(success ?"usbGenericHidCommunication:writeReportToDevice(): -> Write report succeeded"
                                : "usbGenericHidCommunication:writeReportToDevice(): -> Write report failed!");
```

Read Report Code:

```
nonManagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(inputReportBuffer.Length);
nonManagedOverlapped = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(hidOverlapped));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(hidOverlapped, nonManagedOverlapped, false);

// Read the input report buffer
   Debug.WriteLine("usbGenericHidCommunication:readReportFromDevice(): -> Attempting to ReadFile");
success = Kernel32.ReadFile(
                deviceInformation.ReadHandle,
                nonManagedBuffer,
                inputReportBuffer.Length,
                ref numberOfBytesRead,
                nonManagedOverlapped);

            if (!success)
            {
                // We are now waiting for the FileRead to complete
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    "usbGenericHidCommunication:readReportFromDevice(): -> ReadFile started, waiting for completion...");

                // Wait a maximum of 3 seconds for the FileRead to complete
                var result = Kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(eventObject, 3000);

                switch (result)
                {
                        // Has the ReadFile completed successfully?
                    case Constants.WaitObject0:

                        // Get the number of bytes transferred
                        Kernel32.GetOverlappedResult(deviceInformation.ReadHandle, nonManagedOverlapped, ref numberOfBytesRead, false);

                        Debug.WriteLine("usbGenericHidCommunication:readReportFromDevice(): -> ReadFile successful (overlapped) {0} bytes read", numberOfBytesRead);
                        break;

                        // Did the FileRead operation timeout?
                    case Constants.WaitTimeout:

                        // Cancel the ReadFile operation
                        Kernel32.CancelIo(deviceInformation.ReadHandle);
```

Comment: The `Debug.WriteLine` causes a short delay, but only in debug mode.  Since your program is delay sensitive, that might be the only reason it works in debug.

Comment: Also, don't assume that failure means pending I/O.  You need to check `GetLastError` in order to tell (pinvoke has already fetched the last-error value, you just need to look at it)